# R plotly: Filter data labels (by "color") for a stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using plotly to create a stacked bar chart with data labels.

I have created a cumsum variable within the dataframe to use for "layout(annotations=list(y=~cumsum..." which displays as intended when all "colors" are shown (figure 1), but labeling is incorrect when "colors" are deselected from viewing filter (figure 2).

[Bar Chart All Colors (figure1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy4nu.jpg)

[Bar Chart Filtered (figure2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28DBx.jpg)

code is shown below.  How can I get data labels to display properly when filtering "colors"?

```
library(plotly)
dt <- data.frame(noiseLevel=sort(rep(seq(10,50,10),5)),
                 temperature=rep(seq(50,90,10),5),
                 testScore=c(30,75,20,50,70,
                             40,60,45,20,50,
                             30,20,30,40,30,
                             60,30,60,20,50,
                             30,50,20,40,60))
dt <- within(dt, {
  csum <- ave(testScore, noiseLevel, FUN=cumsum)})

plot_ly(data=dt,
        x = ~noiseLevel,        
        y = ~testScore,
        color=~factor(temperature),
        type='bar') %>%
  layout(barmode='stack',
         annotations = list(x=~noiseLevel, y=~csum, text=~testScore,
                            xanchor = 'center', yanchor = 'center',
                            showarrow = FALSE))
```

Comment: this (https://plot.ly/r/horizontal-bar-charts/) might be useful. Scroll down to Color Palette for Bar Chart